Trying to run Appium script in Real device ,App is successfully installed through appium but throws Socket hangup error
I have Installed latest appium server and connected iphone 11 device having IOS Version 16.1 ,Able to install ipa file through appium but script not able to progress further after installation.Throws Socket hangup for all scenarios .
Below are the capabilities added with values .
iOSDeviceUDID
iOSDeviceName
iOSPlatformName
iOSDeviceVersion
iOSAutomationName
iOSApp
Please provide suggestion to fix this issue
Installed Appium Latest version
Installed Node npm Latest version
Ran Appium server after connecting real device ,App is installed successfully.But not able to progress the script further .All scenarios throws socket hangup error.
